# Duda sobre constexpr

Tags: c++, constexpr, abogado-del-lenguaje

¿Por qué, no usar siempre la palabra reservada `constexpr` cuando definimos métodos o funciones? Si calcula todo lo que pueda en compilacion y lo qué no, lo halla en ejecución, sin ocasionar error.

Answer (score 4):

#### Problema.

El cualificador `constexpr` no funciona de una manera intuitiva. Al contrario de lo que dices, no existen los métodos `constexpr`:

```
struct Entero
{
    constexpr int uno() { return 1; }
//  ~~~~~~~~~ <--- El retorno es constexpr, no el método.
};

struct Disparate
{
    int disparatado() constexpr { return 1; } // ESTO NO COMPILA!! :(
//                    ~~~~~~~~~ <--- Método constexpr.
};
```

En el código anterior, podríamos pensar que el método `Entero::uno` es `constexpr`, pero en realidad lo es el `int` retornado, éste código:

```
int main()
{
    Entero e;
    return e.uno();
}
```

Genera este asm:

```
main: # @main
  mov eax, 1
  ret
```

Podemos pensar que está retornando `1` (en lugar de llamar al método) porque ha calculado en tiempo de compilación que `e.uno()` era `1`, pero obtenemos exactamente el mismo asm sin marcar `Entero::uno` como `constexpr`, es decir: se trata de una optimización del compilador no una optimización del programador.

Puedes marcar un objeto completo como `constexpr` pero esto hará que sea `const` implícitamente, provocando errores contraintuitivos:

```
int main()
{
    constexpr Entero e;
    return e.uno(); // ERROR!! La función uno no es const
}
```

El mismo problema encontramos al retornar un objeto como `constexpr`:

```
constexpr Entero f() { return {}; }

int main()
{
    return f().uno(); // ERROR!! La función uno no es const
}
```

Para solucionar el problema anterior basta con marcar `Entero::uno` como `const`:

```
struct Entero
{
    constexpr int uno() const { return 1; }
    //                  ~~~~~ <--- Método constante, retorno constexpr
};

constexpr Entero f() { return {}; }

int main()
{
    constexpr Entero e;
    return e.uno() + f().uno(); // Correcto!!
}
```

El código anterior genera este asm:

```
main: # @main
  mov eax, 2
  ret
```

Que generará igualmente sin la presencia de `constexpr`.

#### Conclusión.

El cualificador `constexpr` es una herramienta para ayudar al compilador a hacer optimizaciones, pero (casi) nunca seremos más listos que el compilador, usar ese cualificador puede ayudar a mover algunos cálculos a tiempo de compilación (que igualmente el compilador puede deducir cómo hacerlo sin nuestra ayuda) así que el objetivo no debería ser usar `constexpr` a diestro y siniestro para ayudar al compilador a hacer algo que ya haría igualmente.

Igual que cualquier herramienta a nuestra disposición `constexpr` debe ser usado cuando se necesita, no debe ser forzado su uso. ¿Cuándo se necesita? Pues cuando queramos asegurar una operación en tiempo de ejecución, aunque el compilador lo fuera a hacer igualmente añadir `constexpr` denota la intencionalidad del código, lo que hace que sea más comprensible para nosotros y otras personas con las que trabajemos.

No caigamos en la trampa del [martillo de oro](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martillo_de_oro).

Answer (score 4):

El uso de `constexpr`, aplicado al valor devuelto por funciones, presenta un *pequeño* problema: **limita lo que podemos hacer dentro de la función**.

En C++14 estas limitaciones se han relajado, pero en C++11, **dentro del cuerpo** de una función `constexpr` solo se admiten:

- Sentencias *nulas* (un `;`).
- Declaraciones `static_assert( )`.
- Declaraciones `typedef` y `alias` que no definan clases o enumeraciones.
- Declaraciones `using`;
- Directivas `using`;
- **El cuerpo solo puede ser y contener 1 solo `return`**.

Este último punto es, para mi, el mayor limitante:

```
constexpr int test( int a, int b ) {
  if( a == b ) return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

[Si intentamos compilarlo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Crfvs0xjVlvLYqck), obtenemos:

> In function 'constexpr int test(int, int)':
>   error: body of 'constexpr' function 'constexpr int test(int, int)' not a return-statement

La forma correcta sería:

```
constexpr int test( int a, int b ) {
  return a == b ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Esto es debido a que, explícitamente, estamos indicándole al compilador que el resultado de esa función **es susceptible** de ser calculado en tiempo de compilación; las capacidades del compilador para estos casos (optimizaciones en tiempo de compilación) son bastante limitadas: se limitan a ciertas operaciones aritméticas y cierta capacidad de *recursión*.

No obstante, el declarar una función `constexpr` presenta algunas ventajas tambien:

```
int test( int a, int b ) {
  return a == b ? 1 : 2;
}

int main( ) {
  char tmp[test( 1, 2 )];

  return 0;
}
```

> warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'tmp': char tmp[test( 1, 2 )];

Sin embargo, si añadimos `constexpr`:

```
constexpr int test( int a, int b ) {
  return a == b ? 1 : 2;
}

int main( ) {
  char tmp[test( 1, 2 )];

  return 0;
}
```

No se producen errores ni avisos, y compila correctamente.

Ahora, si cambiamos los valores `literales` ...

```
constexpr int test( int a, int b ) {
  return a == b ? 1 : 2;
}

int main( ) {
  int a = 1, b = 2;

  char tmp[test( a, b )];

  return 0;
}
```

> warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'tmp': char tmp[test( a, b )];

Lo cual ilustra otra limitación de estas funciones (bastante lógica): **solo se realiza la optimización cuando los argumentos son, a su vez, `constexpr`**. Con lo cual se nos limita aún mas su utilidad practica.

Para mas información, en inglés: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)

Para finalizar: `constexpr`, mas que para el compilador, es **para el programador**, para indicarle/recordarle/limitarle que determinada función quiere ser optimizado, y obligarle a escribir un código que el compilador **puede llegar a optimizar mas** que otro, **sin tener garantía** de que dicha optimización tendrá lugar.

Comment: @eferion ¡ Huy ! Cierto. Corregido. Gracias :-)